# Cordova Cannot Play file on Windows 10

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-universal

I am using the latest verion of Cordova + VS2015.

When I try to play an mp3 file that is included as part of the app in a windows10 app, I get an error (code: 1)

The play works fine when run under iOS and Android, it's only windows 10 that seems to be the problem.

I have tried a number of variations on the path "/myfile.mp3", "myfile.mp3", "/www/myfile.mp3", "www/myfile.mp3" all with the same result.  I tried a file name that does not exist and get the same error.  This leads me to beleive that the path is not correct.  If I print window.location.pathname, I get "/www/index.html", so, I suspect that "/www/myfile.mp3" should work.

The file has been added to the project, it is showing up in the www directory in the platforms folder.

Here is the code, basically cut right from the manual

```
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
    var myMedia = new Media('/www/myfile.mp3', function () {
            console.log('success');
    }, function (e) {
            console.log(e); // I always land here, where is is 'code: 1'
    }, function (e) {
            console.log(e);
    });
    myMedia.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "ms-appx:" scheme will solve the problem. See App Package Section of the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx):

> To access files stored inside the application package, but from code where there is no inferred root authority, specify the **ms-appx:** scheme.

In your case, the path should be modified to "ms-appx:///www/myfile.mp3", if current platform is windows(need to install cordova-plugin-device as pre-work here):

```
var url = "";
if (device)
{
    if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == "windows") {
        url = "ms-appx:///www/myfile.mp3";
    } else {
        url = "/myfile.mp3";
    }
}
var myMedia = new Media(url, function () {
    console.log('success');
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e); // I always land here, where is is 'code: 1'
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
myMedia.play();
```

Comment: That section of the documentation was confusing to me.  

I tried your suggestion, it did not work.  Oddly, when I call play(), NONE of the handlers fire.  HOWEVER, if I call play again, the status handler gets fired with a status of 1.

It seems that the play is now hanging?

I tried a few variations on the file path... none of them worked.

Comment: @JeffG Well, it is odd. It works by my side. Could you share a basic demo project that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: sure, how can I get you the zip? (sorry for the dumb question).  One more thing, this string works "var myMedia = new Media('ms-appx-web://io.cordova.myappda2acc/www/myfile.mp3', function () {"

Comment: @JeffG  you can upload the demo to Github or Onedrive or some other online Repositories, and share the link to your personal repository.

Comment: To close the loop on this (finally), I found that I had to formulate the uri to include the "WindowsStoreIdentityName" that was specified in my config.xml.

So, if I have "<preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="mycompany.myapp" />" in the config.xml, I needed to use:
`var myMedia = new Media("ms-appx-web://mycompany.myapp/www/mySound.mp3");
myMedia.play();`